# Search marked word with single keystroke?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code (current, v1.81.1) to mark a word, then search for this, with a **single** keystroke?

In one of my earlier editors, I used to mark something, then hit F3, which would jump to the next occurrence immediately. One keystroke. Very convenient.

Currently, in Visual Studio Code, I find myself hitting Cmd-F, then Enter, to achieve the same. Two keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press F1 -> open keyboard shortcuts
And then search for "find". I think the behavior you described is "Find next Selection" (for me Ctrl+F3):
[image]

Comment: Oh my, so easy? On my Mac it's Cmd-F3 and working out of the box. Thx.